# Wininet http call without callback

Tags: windows, http, asynchronous, wininet

I'm trying to send a GET method with wininet

```
InternetOpenUrl(hOpen, "http://ip/test.php?val=xxx", NULL,NULL,0, NULL);
```

But I don't want/need to wait for the response.

Is it possible to achieve this **easily** without using the whole INTERNET_FLAG_ASYNC/callback system ?

Comment: INTERNET_FLAG_ASYNC and INTERNET_NO_CALLBACK ? Run it on a thread?

Comment: Yes, but I get ERROR_IO_PENDING after InternetOpenUrl() ?? How can I get this error while I cannot (and don't want to) use the callback (according to msn doc !?)

Comment: This return code probably appears regardless of whether you specify a callback or not; as long as you have `INTERNET_FLAG_ASYNC`, this is what the API would return.
You do not have to treat it as an error though, if you do a fire and forget.